# pandas series finds strings which has a specific as their last chars

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in a `df` that has a minus sign, i.e. `-` as last chars in some of the column string values. now I want to find these strings, I am wondering how to do that,

```
df['amount']
0          3.60-
1          1.70
2          1.80
3          1.20
4          1.22-
Name: amount, Length: 5, dtype: object
```

so for each string, I can do

```
df['amount'][default_int_index] = df['amount'][default_int_index][-1:] + df['amount'][default_int_index][:-1]
```

to put the `-` at the front of the string. So the results will look like,

```
0          -3.60
1          1.70
2          1.80
3          1.20
4          -1.22
```

and then convert the whole series into `float64`,

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].astype(np.float64)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.str.endswith` i.e

```
mask = df['Amount'].str.endswith('-')
```

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: Amount, dtype: bool
```

For conditional replacement use `np.where` i.e

```
df['Amount'] = np.where(mask,'-'+df['Amount'].str[:-1],df['Amount']).astype(float)
```

Ouptut :

```
0   -3.60
1    1.70
2    1.80
3    1.20
4   -1.22
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace`:

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.replace(r'(.+)-', r'-\1').astype(float)
```

Or use `\d+\.\d+` for match `float` number:

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.replace(r'(\d+\.\d+)-', r'-\1').astype(float)

print (df)
   amount
0   -3.60
1    1.70
2    1.80
3    1.20
4   -1.22
```

Comment: how to also consider string like `'-      354.72'` in regex

Comment: Sorry, not understand.

Comment: never mind, I think your 2nd regex works fine when there is a string value like `'    354.72-'` (has leading spaces in the string) in `amount` column

Comment: Yes, it match floats only.

Comment: Regex way of doing ? Nice one